# How to get Camelcase Class Fields in Django Template

Tags: django

I have problems to get the right class called in the django template:

My model looks like this (it is m2m connected to a corresponding user class (which is extended by my person class )
model.

```
class GroupUnit(MetaData):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

in the template:

```
{% for group_member in user.person.group_unit_set.all%}
    {{group_member.name}}  //FAILS

{% endfor %}
```

How do i get the fields of GroupUnit in the template?

Comment: do not use foreign key related name notations ("group_unit_set"), just use the m2m field name you declared in the Person model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose there is a `ForeignKey` field pointing to `Person` from `GroupUnit` model (maybe inherited from `MetaData`?), there would be a related manager called `groupunit_set` on `Person` by default. It's not `'group_unit_set'`, unless the `ForeignKey` field is like `ForeignKey(Person, related_name='group_unit_set', ...)`.